# Какой селектор написать, чтобы была проверка сразу по всему тексту?

Tags: css, xpath, test-automation

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как сделать что-то типа //p[text(),'Each 1h 0m 0s late, deduct 20% of the total points'] ?

Comment: "как сделать что-то типа" - говорим ахалай-махалай и как-то делается... Если серьезно, что за селектор, куда написать, проверка на что, что-то типа ЧЕГО?

Comment: @Zombotron У меня есть тег с текстом внутри, каждое слово которого начинается с новой строки. Мне нужен селектор, по которому я смогу получать весь текст из этого тега, только селектор должен быть икспас, по тексту.

Comment: pps = document.querySelectorAll('.className'); Потом в цикле перебрать все pps, взять innerHTML и искать в нем нужное, отформатировав предвварительно. Вообще, есть селектор и по содержимому (в jQ, по крайней мере), но боюсь, что из-за переводов строк там танцы с бубном будут. в css такого нет, только js.

Comment: xpath поддерживает такое: $x("//*[@class='className'][text()='innerHTML']")

Comment: или так, если подстрока только известна: $x("//*[@class='className'][contains(text(),'text')]")

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$x("//*[@class='className'][contains(.,'text')]"; // (консольный вариант,  в коде не работает)
```

так будет выдирать любую подстроку в innerHTML с захватом всех внутренностей. Просто, text() такое вот "text1<br>text2" интерпретирует как три ноды: text1 - 1, <br> - 2, text2 - 3.
Но т.к. ковыряние с xpath цепляет тот же js + еще немного всякого, то я бы все-таки воспользовался чистыми js и html-dom:

```
pps = document.querySelectorAll('p.className');
for(i=0; i<pps.length; i++){
    el = pps[i];
    txt = el.innerHTML;
    if(txt.indexOf('текст для поиска') != -1){
       // колдунство над найденными и удовлетворяющими поиску el
    }
}
```